Why Kotlin delegation is different between an Intellij Project and a Gradle project
My Intellij Version is 2024.2.4 (Build #IU-242.23726.103, built on October 23, 2024)
I created the following code in :

an Intellij project : File > New > Project... > Kotlin

Build system: Intellij / OpenJdk 23


And in a Gradle project : File > New > Project... > Kotlin

Build system: Gradle / OpenJdk 23 / Kotlin



interface Base {
    fun printMessage()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun printMessage() { println(x) }
}


class BaseImpl2(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun printMessage() { println("2 $x") }
}

class Derived(var b: Base) : Base by b {

}

fun main() {
    val base1 = BaseImpl(10)
    val base2 = BaseImpl(12)
    val derived = Derived(base1)
    derived.printMessage()
    derived.b = base2
    derived.printMessage()
}

Intellij project execution outputs :
10
12

Gradle project execution outputs :
10
10

Finally, I'm experiencing in the gradle version what exeplain here.
The difference in the bytecode generated is there :
public final class Editeur implements Base {
   @NotNull
   private Base b;
   // $FF: synthetic field
   private final Base $$delegate_0;

But we don't have the final delegate in Intellij :
public final class Editeur implements Base {
   @NotNull
   private Base b;

Why the bytecode generated is different between the both projects ?
Complements
Complement 1
Version of kotlin is both 2.0.20 for the lib, not for the compiler :
Gradle
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

...

Gradle is using 2.0.20 plugin, with the 2.0.20 koltinc version.
Intellij Version
I have the version during the build logs
Executing pre-compile tasks…
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Kotlin: connecting to daemon
Kotlin: compiling [untitled]
Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.9.24-release-822 (JRE 23.0.1+11-39)
Kotlin: Language version 2.0 is experimental, there are no backwards compatibility guarantees for new language and library features
Kotlin: performing incremental compilation analysis
Checking dependencies… [untitled]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Updating dependency information… [untitled]

Intellij is using the 2.0.20 kotlin libs but the 1.9.24 kotlinc version
Complement 2
This is reproduced on Ubuntu version of Intellij and Windows on different desktop (This appeared during a training session)
Complement 3
I put the project in github there. You can play with the src/test1/Base2.kt

Which Kotlin version do both projects use?

Based on my interpretation of the spec, I think outputting 12 here is non-compliant. I cannot reproduce this though.

Both version are 2.0.20... I just added information in the question

@Sweeper did you create the project with the last version of idea ? As an Intellij project (Not Gradle) ?
I'm agree with you, the 12 is not normal and there is a ticket to make the object that supporting the delegation mutable... But the real question is Why the behavior is different between Gradle that should encapsulate kotlinc 2.0.20 and Intellij that call directly kotlinc...

I was able to reproduce this when using a 1.9 compiler but the language and API versions are set to 2.0, which are the defaults for a new IntelliJ project. I cannot reproduce this with the compiler version set to 2.0.20 though.

I put the project in github.

I was able to reproduce the 10 12 result with the aforementioned settings using gradle too. It seems like this is just the default settings of a new IntelliJ project not making much sense.

@Sweeper ok, it seems that the old kotlinc-jvm built-in the intellij is not compiled as it is specified...

I checked out the GitHub repo, and it clearly says compiler version is 1.9.24 in the settings. What makes you think you are compiling with 2.0.20?

You right this is a 1.9.24... Bad reading, sorry.
The mutability of the delegate is a question since 2018, the difference of behavior between 1.9.x and 2.0.20 is strange anyway, no ?

@sweeper : What makes me think that I was in 2.0.20, is in the project structure, you have dependencies in 2.0.20 versions of kotlin libs...

Ah I see. That's just the version of the standard lib, not the version of the compiler.

In a newly-created IntelliJ project, the compiler version is set to 1.9.24, but the language and API versions are set to 2.0.

It is this combination of settings that produces the bug. If you use an API and language version of 1.9, or if you change the compiler version to 2.0+, the "10 12" behaviour is no longer reproducible.
On the other hand, a new gradle project uses the 2.0.20 compiler
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"
}

If you wrote this instead, you can reproduce the same behaviour as the IntelliJ project.
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(23)
    compilerOptions {
        apiVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
        languageVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
    }
}


@weeper But that really strange that we just have a warn on the property definition as var b: Base with that comments Delegating to 'var' property does not take its changes into account ... Finally, we should make it as error, no ?

@BenjaminJalon That could be something you can suggest on Kotlin Discussions. Making this change now would be a breaking change, though.
